# Fail2ban log only goes a very short amount of time back

Tags: fail2ban

I have `fail2ban` running with default settings on a xubuntu machine. `/var/log` contains 5 files:

- `fail2ban.log`
- `fail2ban.log.1`
- `fail2ban.log.2.gz`
- `fail2ban.log.3.gz`
- `fail2ban.log.4.gz`

Totaling about 15 KB.

`fail2ban.log.4.gz` contains the oldest entries, going back roughly a month. Seems like `fail2ban` will periodically delete older logs so they don't take up too much space, but I want to change this behavior.

How is this specified? Max size, oldest log, or something else? Where can I configure the behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) utility is the normal way to manage logs on a Linux system. The config files for the variuos logs are nrmally found in /etc/logrorate.d. I would go looking for /etc/logrotate.d/fail2ban (or similar) to find out how it is being managed. Note that some parmeters may also be specified in /etc/logrotate.conf too.